# How to delete a file from a directory folder with php?

Tags: php, directory

I'm echoing out users images from a folder, i don't have the names of the images stored. so i'm trying to take the `src` of the image file on `.image_delete_btn` click and pass that to delete_image.php where it can delete the file. I can't see why this isn't working. any suggestions are much appreciated.

PS: no errors, the `delete_image.php` script simply returns NULL, but the ajax request is being called. But I don't think the data is being passed.

HTML/PHP: (displays images from folder)

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
  $image = $files[$i];
  $supported_file = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
  );

  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
    echo '<div class="card company_photo_card">';   
    echo '<div class="image_delete_btn flaticon-error"></div>';  
    echo '<div class="img_hover_effect">';  
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image"  class="company_photos" />';
    echo '</div>';   
    echo '</div>';   

  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
```

AJAX:

```
$('.image_delete_btn').click(function() {

  var filename = $(this).next("div").first("img").attr("src");

  $('.loading_gif').show();
  m = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this image?");

  if (m == true) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'confirm/delete_image.php',
      data: {
        filename: filename
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $('.loading_gif').hide();
        $(filename).fadeOut();

      },
      error: function(data) {
        switch (data.info) {
          case 'delete_error':
            delete_error();
            break;
          case 'delete_success':
            delete_success();
            break;

        }

      }
    });
  } else {

    $('.loading_gif').hide();
  }



});
```

delete_image.php

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

 $filename = $_POST['filename'];

 $file = basename($ImageData); 

  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    $response["message"] = 'delete_success';
    $errors++;  
  }

 var_dump($filename);

 echo json_encode($response); 
 exit();

 }else{

echo"acces denied";

}
?>
```

Comment: `"But I don't think the data is being passed."` - What happens when you check and find out?  In your browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request being made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: The AJAX call is being made, but no data is being passed. the request payload is `[object Object]`

Comment: `var filename = $(this).find("img").attr("src")` tried ?

Comment: @Vikrant yep, no change.